# Saving each .html page in a webpage by searching recursively with either a script or a tool?

Tags: html, linux, recursion, web

I was wondering if it was possible to get a tool that would recursively search through a webpage and save each page that it landed on as a separate .html file.  Ive looked at wget, but I wasn't sure if it fulfilled that specific functionality.

Any solution will work, as long as it works successfully for linux or windows.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this is you're solution :     https://www.httrack.com/page/1/en/index.html

with a tutorial : http://www.wikihow.com/Copy-a-Website

Comment: Thats what I needed.  Thanks!